# Why is my Bootstrap datetimepicker not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

Hi I've added a bootstrap `datetimepicker` to my website but it seems like it's not working.
I Am I missing something? or doing something wrong? Please help.The control is in a bootstrap modal but as far as I know it doesn't restrict your accessibility which is the only reason I can think of for it not working...

This is the referances I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.contextmenu.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mycss.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />

<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.contextmenu.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

this is my control:

```
<div class="row" id="div9" runat="server">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="margin-top: 5px">
         <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text="Start Date" CssClass="form-control" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Black" Font-Size="14px"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_start_date" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="SingleLine" Width="100%" ForeColor="Black" Font-Bold="True"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () {
            $('#txt_start_date').datetimepicker({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD', useCurrent: true });
            });
       });
</script>
```

Comment: what error you getting in console?

Comment: z-index may issues ,pls try with set <style>
    .datepicker {
      z-index: 1600 !important; /* has to be larger than 1050 */
    }
</style>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boostrap 4 not support datetimepicker.
Change file bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js

```
'collapse in' 

expanded = $parent.find('.in'),
closed = $parent.find('.collapse:not(.in)'),

expanded.removeClass('in');
closed.addClass('in');
```

to

```
'collapse show'


expanded = $parent.find('.show'),
closed = $parent.find('.collapse:not(.show)'),

expanded.removeClass('show');
 closed.addClass('show');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code, no need to use Jquery. Use input type date instead of text.

```
<input type="date" class="form-control"/>
```

[Working Fiddle with & without Jquery](https://jsfiddle.net/rajtri/jrfhbtq9/10/)